# C# - Close messagebox of other process

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, messagebox, user32

I have a multi-threaded application, that fires off a lot of similar processes.

Sometimes one of the processes throws up a MessageBox with an error, and this has a negative effect on the whole application.

I would like to be able to fish out this MessageBox, and send an OK/CLOSE button command to it.

The big issue is that the MessageBox/Window doesn't have a title, so I can't use this:

```
IntPtr window = FindWindow(null, "");
while (window != IntPtr.Zero)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Window found, closing...");

      //use some function to close the window    
      SendMessage((int)window, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);

      window = IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

How could I adjust this code, or how could I use something similar, that would find the Window without the title, and close it?

Would I need to iterate thru the processes? Remember the processes have similar names, so even though I could get all processes with the specific name, I would have problems finding the one that causes the issue...

PS: I can't edit the source-code of the application, I have to make this small little FIX for now.

Comment: Clearly this other program isn't intended to be automated in this fashion (or you've missed a flag/setting to tell it not to show UI). It may be time to look for a more suitable program/component.

Comment: That's currently not an option, sadly.

Comment: Have you tried [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)?